# Line Integral of an unknown curve?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Solved: This is a case where the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals can be applied.

I am confused about the wording of this question:

Evaluate $\int_C\ (xy^2+1)\,dx\, +\ x^2y\,dy$ where $C$ is an unknown curve from $(1,-2)$ to $(3,3)$.

I think I am allowed to simply parametrize a line from the initial point to the final point like so:

$\mathbf r = (1+2t)\mathbf i +(-2+5t) \mathbf j$

where $0\le t \le 1$

Would this be correct? What do they mean by an unknown curve?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $xy^2dz$?

Comment: No that is exactly how the question is worded

Comment: The question would be correct if it were asked to find $\int_C(xy^2+1)dx+x^2ydy$ because here the vector field $(xy^2+1,x^2y)$ is conservative and you can find the line integral along any suitable curve and path between the two points.

Comment: Thank you! This is a case where the fundamental theorem of line Integrals can be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the integrand is exact, you can choose any path that joins the two points. The line segment you’ve chosen looks pretty straightforward in this case. Alternatively, you can find a function $F$ such that the integrand is $\mathrm dF$ and compute $F(3,3)-F(1,-2)$. Such a function is given by the integral $$F(x,y)=\int_0^1x\cdot(xt\cdot(yt)^2+1)+y\cdot(xt)^2\cdot yt\,dt.$$ It’s not immediately obvious to me which way will be less work for this problem.